# Python pandas - Does read_csv keep file open?

Tags: pandas

When using pandas `read_csv()` method, does it keep the file open or it closes it (discard the file descriptor)?

If it keeps it, how do I close it after I finish using the dataframe?

Comment: You can expect that every properly designed reading method that opens a file descriptor also closes it before returning.

Comment: That what I expected, I just wanted to be sure..

Comment: I also expected that, but I got surprises. I can't explain why Windows tells me I can't move thé file because python is holding it... ( but perhaps it is spyder, à python Ide...)

Comment: I'm curious to know if this is guaranteed (closing the file descriptor) if an exception is thrown while the file is being parsed and the panda is being constructed.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you pass it an open file it will keep it open (reading from the current position), if you pass a string then `read_csv` will open and close the file.

---

In python if you open a file but forget to close it, python will close it for you at the end of the function block (during garbage collection).

```
def foo():
    f = open("myfile.csv", "w")
    ...
    f.close()  # isn't actually needed
```

*i.e. if you call a python function which opens a file, unless the file object is returned, the file is auto<s>magically</s>matically closed.*

Note: The preferred syntax is the `with` block (which, as well as closing `f` at the end of the `with` block, defines the `f` variable only inside the `with` block):

```
def foo():
    with open("myfile.csv", "w") as f:
        ...
```

Comment: What about using `Iterator = True`? I am reading some Python code that parse a big file chunk by chunk, at it seems to need a `store = pd.read_csv(...); store.close()` syntax. I still end up with a warning about the file being left open during my unit tests.