# Opening CSV file with pd.read_csv - any purpose for context manager?

Tags: python, file, pandas, dataframe

I'm beginning to read [Elegant SciPy](https://github.com/elegant-scipy) by Nunez-Iglesias et. al, and when opening the first dataset in the book (a `.txt` file), the author uses

```
filename = 'data/counts.txt'
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    data_table = pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0) # Parse file with pandas
```

But I thought that [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) would close the file, given that it is opening given a file descriptor (see [Andy Hayden's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29418461/5636510) ).

So is there any purpose to the context manager here, or could we just as safely write

```
filename = 'data/counts.txt'
data_table = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a file-handle to `read_csv` or pass in a filename. In the first case you create the file-handle, so it's your responsibility to close it again. However if you pass in a file**name** then `read_csv` will open the file on your behalf and close it again (when appropriate).

So in most cases it's the easier option to just provide the filename:

```
data_table = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
```

Note that the option to pass in file handles allows you to pass in file-like objects:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> myio = StringIO("""a b c
... 0 1 2 3
... 1 4 5 6""")
>>> pd.read_csv(myio, sep=' ', header=0, index_col=0)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

However it's rather rare to actually pass a **real** file-handle to `read_csv`. The only case I could think of is when pandas can't open the file itself. For example if it was compressed using a uncommon compression algorithm.

Comment: Sure, so maybe the author is just trying to instill a good practice but its not needed here. Thanks, I just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: I think so. I don't know if there is ever a good reason to pass file-handles to `read_csv`. However maybe the file is compressed (using a format unknown to pandas) and then you have no other choice but to uncompress it yourself and pass the filehandle to `read_csv`. In that case it's good to know that the file-handle is your responsibility.

Comment: Just found a good use case: when I'm using an abstraction layer, such as Pyfilesystem, I open the file using `fs` module and then pass the `filehandle` on to pandas.