# Pandas Excel import only works for a single function call - error on second function call

Tags: django, excel, pandas

I loose the ability to open a second excel worksheet in Pandas after the first function call.

Here the `import_info` works but the `import_data` gives me an error trying to open the same Excel file in the exact same manner.

The file path is still there but I am getting `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType`:

```
#  get the account info
a = import_info ( file )

# get the data
cf = import_data ( file )
```

the first function works fine:

```
def import_info ( file ):
    xl = pd.ExcelFile ( file )
    df = xl.parse ( "info", index = False )
    data = df [ ... ]
    return data
```

the second function that is getting the path error:

```
def import_data ( file ):
    xl = pd.ExcelFile ( file )
    df = xl.parse ( "data", index = False )
    data = df [ ... ]
    return data
```

I am very confused why this works once but not twice?

Thank You

Comment: the file that you are passing to the second function is corrupted or not valid file. try passing the same file to the second one also which you are passing to the fiist function and check if it works

Comment: no, it is the same file.  nothing changes with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) to load both sheets at the same time. The result would be a dictonary with both dataframes.

```py
def get_data(file):
    return pd.read_excel(file, ['info', 'data'])

def prepare_info_df(df):
    ...
    return data

def prepare_data_df(df):
    ...
    return data

df_dict = get_data(file)
info_df = prepare_info_df(df_dict['info'])
data_df = prepare_data_df(df_dict['data'])
```

Comment: This is the best approach to be safe. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark it as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

From this answer: [Python pandas - Does read_csv keep file open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416968/python-pandas-does-read-csv-keep-file-open), it seem that pandas keep the file open from the first call, and that will explain why you can't access it on your second call.

If the `file` argument is a path to the file, I suggest you to use first the `with open` python method who will handle opening / closing the file for you:

```
def import_info(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as open_file:
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(open_file)
        df = xl.parse( "info", index = False )
        data = df[...]
    return data
```

If the `file` argument is a file like object, you might want to call `seek(0)` to reset the pointer.