# pandas read_csv with and without open

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv

I am taking a Coursera course on data science. In one assignment, "read_csv" is used with a file "open" method. In a different assignment, the "read_csv" is used without "open".

```
GDP = pd.read_csv(open('world_bank.csv', 'rb'), header=header_rows)
GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv', header=header_rows)
```

Both seem to work. So I am wondering, what is the difference between the two ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29418461/5916727

Comment: `read_csv` can take both buffer and a string to convert them to a dataframe. So both works. If you use `open`  it will keep the file open. Whereas if you use  string it will open the file and convert the file to dataframe then will close it by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pandas - Does read\_csv keep file open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416968/python-pandas-does-read-csv-keep-file-open)