# Should I use `with open(file):` if I `pd.read_csv`?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file-io

## **Context**

[I've learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8011836/5433628) that one should use `with open` when reading files in Python:

```
import csv

with open('employee_birthday.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

([source](https://realpython.com/python-csv/))

However, I've seen multiple examples where this structure is not used when using pandas' `pd.read_csv`:

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 
# Read data from file 'filename.csv' 
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
data.head()
```

([source](https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read_csv-load-data-from-csv-files/))

## Question

➥ **Should I use `with open():` when reading `.csv` files using pandas' `pd.read_csv`?**
(Or is `pd.read_csv` already smart enough?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pandas - Does read\_csv keep file open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416968/python-pandas-does-read-csv-keep-file-open)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`with open('<>') as file:` method **allows the users need to do line by line operations for single or multiple lines in the file**.

`pandas` handles the files differently. **When you import a file to pandas dataframe, it imports the entire contents of the file to the dataframe**. Opening and closing the file are not needed to be specified since you will be processing the dataframe there on.

Hence, ***when you are reading files to a `pandas dataframe`, `with open ()` is not required.***

Answer (score 4):

pd.read_csv() is smart enough to take care of file opening. It is smart enough to distinguish between file object and file path.

Answer (score 3):

When your importing file into pandas there is no need to open specifically file. You can directly import into pandas dataframe and start using dataframe.

```
exam_data = pd.read_csv('exams.csv', quotechar='"')
exam_data
```

so answer to your question pd.read_csv is enough.

Comment: how is this answer above question? more likely a comment on question.