# pandas read_excel sharing violation

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a couple of time series in a excel file. My goal is to check if the excel file exists. If it does, then load it using `pd.read_excel`, if it doesn't then call a remote server to download the data and then store it into a excel file.

Trying to follow the "ask forgiveness not permission" anti-pattern, I do the following:

```
try:
    citi_px = pd.read_excel(open('citi_credit_px.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='data')
    startdate = yesterday
except IOError:
    startdate = whatever
```

And it seems to work as expected. However, I had the wrong sheet name on my file, which raised a `ValueError` and now the Excel file is locked by Python and I can't modify or delete it. Obvious workaround is to make a copy and modify the copy but I would like to know what's the proper way to:

1) Close the Excel file using Pandas/Python Internals
2) Use context managers for the try catch

I appreciate your suggestions and insight!

Answer (score 2):

refer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416968/python-pandas-does-read-csv-keep-file-open) its same question. Better to use `with` since its going to close the file as well in your try block.

```
def foo():
   with open("myfile.csv", "w") as f:
```

Comment: I saw it before asking. That only accounts for a part of a part of the question. This recommends using a context manager for a basic file open, but in this case we're using pandas, my understanding is that internally a context manager is already in place. Also, my question is how to address a particular problem that your answer is trying to avoid, so one part is how to avoid it, the missing part is how to fix it